# UDP incoming packets not visible in Qt

Tags: c++, qt, sockets, udp

I'm trying to receive UDP packets from an Arduino Uno. Packets are received by the computer(they're visible in wireshark), but aren't seen in my Qt application. There part of my Udp class:

```
 #include "udp.h"

Udp::Udp(QHostAddress adr, quint16 pr) : QObject()
{
    address.setAddress(adr.toString());
    port = pr;
    socket = new QUdpSocket();
    status = socket->bind(address,port);
    connect(socket,SIGNAL(readyRead()), this, SLOT(readUdp()));
}

void Udp::sendUdp(QByteArray out)
{
    socket->writeDatagram(out,address,port);
}

QByteArray Udp::readUdp()
{
    QByteArray input;
    input.resize(socket->pendingDatagramSize());
    QHostAddress sender;
    quint16 senderPort;
    socket->readDatagram(input.data(),input.size(),
                             &sender,&senderPort);

   return input;
}
```

> socket->pendingDatagramSize() returns 0(and -1 sometimes).

Comment: I see no errors in your code, the only reason why you could receive a readyread and find no datagrams to read is because the socket is changed .. but does not seem your case.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know QT, but when using berkely socket API, you need to ensure endian

```
port = htons(pr);
```

When your application is running, you can run netstat -l in a terminal. Your application should appear on the list